# Matrix out of bounds but can't put condition to check bounds

Tags: c++, matrix, geometry, bounds

I have a square matrix, 40 x 40, and a draw circle function that uses [this](https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_intermediate-algebra/s11-02-circles.html) formula.
I have another function that reads input from a file, the point itself (x0, y0) and the type of circle (0 or 1) and the radius.

```
void cerc(int x0, int y0, int r, int** matriceHarta, int tip, int n, int m)
{
    if (r == 0)
        return;
    int x, y, xx, rr;

    for (rr = r * r, x = -r; x <= r; x++)
        for (xx = x * x, y = -r; y <= r; y++)
            if (xx + (y * y) <= rr && matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] == 0)
            {
                if (tip == 0)
                    matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] = -5;
                else if (tip == 1)
                    matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] = -6;
            }
}
```

N and M are the rows and columns, but right now they are both equal.
The matrix is allocated dynamically and is transmitted via the `int** matriceHarta` parameter.

If I put the point on `(39, 39)` and I give it the radius 5, the program returns a negative exit code, which I found out is an out of bounds related error. I looked over the for loops and it makes sense that that'd be the error and tried to create the condition `if((x0 + x) < n && (y0 + y) < m)` to check the bounds, but it still gives the error.

Question is, what am I doing wrong? For contrast, `point(37, 4) with radius = 2 is OK`, but `point(38, 4) with radius = 2 is not OK`

This is the attempted fix:

```
for (rr = r * r, x = -r; x <= r; x++)
        for (xx = x * x, y = -r; y <= r; y++)
            if (xx + (y * y) <= rr && matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] == 0 
            && (((x0+x) < n) && ((y0+y) < m))  )
            //^^^^^ this is the condition i was talking about
            {
                if (tip == 0)
                    matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] = -5;
                else if (tip == 1)
                    matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] = -6;
            }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: please post a [mcve]. A negative exit code is not necessarily an out of bounds access.

Comment: btw using only one/two letter variable names and combinations of similar ones like `x`,`xx`,`x0` makes code extremely hard to read. I'd be surprised if it had no bug.

Comment: it looks extremely fishy that the function does not use `n` or `m`

Comment: please show the version with your attempted fix

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number i added the n and m in the attempted fix afterwards, i edited the question

Comment: `if (xx + (y * y) <= rr && matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] == 0 ` -- Too late -- you've already accessed items potentially out-of-bounds.  That stuff after the `&&` doesn't happen first.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i thought it didnt matter for some strange reason, thanks, that was it

Comment: *i thought it didnt matter for some strange reason* -- Probably this should be a duplicate of a question that deals with short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you put your comment as an answer so i can give it the green checkmark and mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are testing for the out-of-bounds condition *after* you have already accessed potential out-of-bounds elements.

Let's break it down into separate lines:

```
if (xx + (y * y) <= rr && matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] == 0 
           && // <-- This binds the conditions
   (((x0+x) < n) && ((y0+y) < m)))
```

The line above the `&&` marked with `<--` is evaluated *before* the line below the `<--`.

In summary, the logical `&&` is always evaluated from left-to-right, where the right side will not be evaluated if the left side evaluates to `false` (short-circuit boolean evaluation).

Thus the fix is to test the bounds condition first (swap the lines in the code above).

However, to make this a little more clear, you could break up the statement into two `if` statements:

```
if (x0+x < n && y0+y < m)
{
   if  (xx + (y * y) <= rr && matriceHarta[x0 + x][y0 + y] == 0)
   {
        ...
   }
}
```